# unlock android device manager remotely

Tags: android, unlock

Is there an option to remotely unlock the online Android Device Manager's lock feature if I have the password? I do not see an option to do this but have read a couple examples of entering code to do something similar:

Open your terminal and type:

adb shell
Now enter these commands:

su
rm /data/system/cm_gesture.key
reboot
If a lockscreen appears after reboot, it should accept any pattern.

I have read many answers in forums but I do not have my phone, it was stolen and I am desperate. Also, I have the Google Device Manager password I used to lock my Samsung Active S5 after it was stolen. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try powering it off and powering back up again.. 
For me the screen for entering passcode came up after rebooting..

I was so scared too, it seems to be a bug..before rebooting I couldn't find anyway to bring up the password screen neither ..

Answer (score 0):

**i too had locked my nubia mini device through android device manager.**

it can be bypassed by rebooting into recovery mode and you need to **format /data and /cache.**

after this restart your **phone through recovery mode it may take 5 to 10 minutes** to finally show "android is updating your apps " something like this.

this method worked on my nubia mini and i thing technically it might work on every android phone that is capable of booting into recovery mode.

**this method would not delete your photos,music,etc.
only contacts and app data will be gone**,i am sure that won't be an issue.